# Very complex FQL queries very slow

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the first 50 posts (posts by friends) from the user's news feed using facebook FQL, as well as each friend's profile information.  I have two queries, which total 10 seconds of processing:

```
SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream 
  WHERE filter_key IN 
     (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid= me() AND type='newsfeed') 
  AND actor_id in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
  LIMIT 50
```

This query returns the user, even if the message is "" (I couldn't find a NOT operator to filter out rows that have "" as a message)

Second query:

```
SELECT pic_big, name,url from profile WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN 
    (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid= me() 
    AND type='newsfeed') 
  AND actor_id in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())) 
  LIMIT 50
```

I've tried other ways to get the data (quicker) however, it returns it in a random order (facebook doesn't guarantee that the data comes out the way it went in).

I could place a "loading" animation on my website but I'd prefer not to because I think that this can be optimized but I'm not sure how.

In the past, I used the graph api but I had to process the results myself, and it was very inefficient (taking over 30+ seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these two queries, you should be able to speed things up quite a bit by combining them into a single multi-query, especially since your second query includes your first query. This one is the most complex, and if you're sending them in separate API calls, Facebook has to perform it twice.

```
{
 'q1':"SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream 
        WHERE filter_key IN 
         (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid= me() AND type='newsfeed') 
          AND actor_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
        LIMIT 50",
  'q2':'SELECT pic_big, name, url, id FROM profile WHERE id IN 
         (SELECT actor_id FROM #q1)'
 }
```

Your two queries take 4072 + 1304 = 5376ms when I run them in the Graph API explorer. The multiquery takes 3475ms. With network latency eliminated from running two separate queries, this should drastically speed up your app.

You can filter out blank messages by adding `AND strlen(message) > 0` to the `WHERE` part of your first query.

You can use `ORDER BY column` to force the return of data in a specific order, but there is no guarantee that you will get all the rows in your result.

Comment: It seemed to work a few times, then after that the two queries gave mismatched results (one query would have maybe as little as 21 results to 45) and the other one would be the same.  The user's posts don't match up with the profile information :(.  I could sort both arrays by ID but then it wouldn't order it by date created.  Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Yes. The easiest way is with two nested FOREACH loops. Modify the q2 query to also return `id`, then loop through the Q1 results. Then for each row in q1, loop through q2 until you find an `id` that matches the `actor_id` in q1. You can have more than one post from each user, so they probably won't match.